# Awaiting simple Task<T> never continues

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, microsoft-graph-api

I have a simple task meant to make a call to the Azure GraphAPI and return the logged in user.  The query works and returns the info as expected.  The problem is if I try to take that data, assign the data to an object and then return that object.  When I do that, the code starts to execute the `await graphclient.Me` line but never continues.  As if it is just waiting for the API to respond.

For some context, I want to return the results so I can use the returned `UserModel` as a property on a view model.

`UserModel` is just a simple class with two string properties.

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
}
```

I make a call to the task:

```
 _loggedInUser = GetSignedInUserDetails().Result;
```

Below is that task that hangs up when trying to return type `UserModel`. If I modify the task to a void task, it executes without issue.

```
private async Task<UserModel>  GetSignedInUserDetails()
{
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = await GraphAPIServices
        .SignInAndInitGraph(AzureAppInfo.UserReadAll);

    UserModel loggedInUser = new UserModel();

    var user =  await graphClient.Me
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();

    loggedInUser.LName = user.GivenName;
    loggedInUser.FName = user.Surname;

    return loggedInUser; 
}
```

I'm sure I am missing something fundamental, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: In `GetSignedInUserDetails` change the first line to `GraphServiceClient graphClient = await GraphAPIServices.SignInAndInitGraph(AzureAppInfo.UserReadAll).ConfigureAwait(false);` and also `.GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` - with that `.ConfigureAwait(false)` you supppress the context switching that will cause the dead lock. Yes, you should also avoid using `Task.Result`.

Comment: In reading the  the link that was provided in the linked question above (https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)  using ConfigureAwait(false) is not best practice.  Best practice would be to have top level methods that async as well.  Which brings me to my problem that triggered this question.  I can't instantiate a view model  as a Task.  So how would I load my _loggedInUser object when the vm is instantiated?

Comment: Well, all my ViewModels have a `Task InitializeAsync(object? parameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` method which I call for that reason.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I need.  Do you have a link or an example on how best to implement that?  I'm trying to wrap my head around all of this.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/SirRufo/WpfWithSplash

Comment: I ended up going the route suggested here, under the Data-Bound Values section.  Thanks for the help!